# Omitting fields on model "save" in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model, which has several "automatic" fields, like this:

```
class Message(Model):
    subject = CharField(max_length = 200)
    message = TextField()
    created = DateTimeField()
    last_status_change = DateTimeField()
    status = CharField(max_length = 10)
```

In my database (Postgres) I set up default values for `created, last_status_change, status` also, I set up a trigger to update `last_status_change` every time `status` changes.

However, when I try to create and save a model instance like this:

```
m = Message(subject = 'Hello', message = 'Long and boring day')
m.save()
```

Django tries to insert NULLs into those missing fields, which is wrong. Is there a way to make it emit insert without those fields or do I have to duplicate my DB functionality in the code?

Thanks!

Comment: where have you put the default values for the fields? there is no default values set in the model.

Comment: @anand they are set up at the database level

Comment: @maksymko set them in the model class. There is a parameter 'default' which can be set to put the default values. Have a look at this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/

Comment: @anand I know about this, I just don't want to do in my code (calculating the current time, for example) what is already done on the database level.

Comment: @maksymko you do not need to calculate the current time, datetime field has its own parameters auto_now, auto_now_add. I guess Django model imposes its parameters on the database.

Comment: @anand auto_now and auto_now_add set time to localtime, while we need it to be UTC

Answer (score 1):

you can try setting blank to true .like below......

```
class Message(Model):
    subject = CharField(max_length = 200)
    message = TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    created = DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    last_status_change = DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = CharField(max_length = 10,blank=True,null=True)

    def save(self):
         self.last_status_change=Datetime.now()
```

Comment: Blank tries to set status to empty string, which is invalid status. From what I see, there is just no way to do what I want in django...

Comment: try and add a method in the model which takes self as the first argument and manupulates the status the way you want it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to put default values into model fields definition and implement special method for changing status or rewrite save() method instead of database level triggers.

Answer (score 0):

You can omit fields on update but on on insert (by design).

If you wish to set your DateTime field to a date (i.e datetime.now) you may also pass a callable to the default argument, and take care of setting the utc time (or whatever you want) yourself:

```
ctime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
```

The above will automatically insert current date and time (utc) as the ctime field value, when saving a new row.

Edit: Just saw you're also looking to set mtime, you could make sure your code runs exactly as you want, and avoid an extra update with a [pre_save signal hook](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#pre-save):

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from myapp.models import MyModel

@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)
def update_mtime(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.mtime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```